# What is the difference between a Service and a Process?

Tags: unix, process, services, threads

From a unix admin standpoint what is the difference please between those terminologies : Service, Process, Thread, Task, Job, Daemon ?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions seeking product, service, or **learning material recommendations** are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Have you searched for that terms anf found an any definitions?

Comment: You guys are harsh

Comment: @DavidPostill erm, could you explain exactly how this is software shopping?

Comment: @blaine it's asking for learning material

Comment: @KyleH Only when people ask to be spoon fed without doing any research at all. And crosspost to the wrong sites ...

Comment: I disagree. There's too much attitude on stack exchange as a whole. I can't change it, but I'll still answer questions for newbies. We all start somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a unix admin standpoint what is the difference please between those terminologies : Service, Process, Thread, Task, Job, Daemon ?

Service is a program that runs continuously in the background.

Process is a program that is running and is assigned a pid, a process ID.

Task is a fuzzy one, I can't think of a concrete example. I believe it's a windows version of a process.

Job is a command to be executed at a certain date/time, usually through cron.

Daemon is pretty much a service, a program that runs in the background. The major distinction is that this one accepts connections from clients on the network.